# Strange IllegalStateException with ViewPager and TextView

Tags: android, android-viewpager, textview, illegalstateexception, android-pageradapter

I have a strange crash on my app.

On my layout, I have a TextView independent of my viewPager, which is with the property `android:layout_below`, so, the TextView's parent is a RelativeLayout with ID **rl**, and ViewPager as well:

[image]

Now, when I change the adapter of my ViewPager, I'm changing the TextView's text at the same time, and I get the following `IllegalStateException`:

```
    ChiamataPOST chiamata = new ChiamataPOST(WSEntity); // My AsyncTask
    chiamata.execute(WS); // I execute it

    cittaSceltaTV.setText("whatever text"); // and I change my textView, I've tried to do it before and after the AsyncTask.
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 4, found: 0

but if I comment the TextView's `setText()`'s function, it works perfectly.

Is that strange? am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call notifyDataSetChanged() on your PageAdapter before calling the setText() on your text view. like below

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
cittaSceltaTV.setText("whatever text");
```

I believe as soon as you call the call the setText(), it's trying to update the list and it throws the IllegalStateException because it notices a discrepancy between the expected item count and the actual one. see below.

```
 Expected adapter item count: 4, found: 0
```

Comment: Thanks... I have been calling notifyDataSetChanged every time I was changing adapter but that one ... but I still don't understand why it happens.

Thank you very much!